# Using pyglet.media (& avbin) on NixOS (no sound plays)

Tags: python, audio, pyglet, nix, nixos

I have a music player that I made some time ago on Windows that I'm trying to get working on NixOS. However, attempting to play any sound files, even with the most basic script possible doesn't do anything.

```py
player = pyglet.media.Player()
source = pyglet.media.load(path)
player.queue(source)
player.play()
```

Nothing happens. There are no errors and it immediately finishes.
I tried downloading AVbin, but the installer doesn't work for NixOS (different file hierarchy).
What can I do to get this to work? I Pyglet even still developed (seems that the installers haven't changed since 2012)?
It would take quite some time to change everything over to PyGame or something else with the same power over volume and time that Pyglet has.

Answer (score 0):

Pyglet dropped avbin a while ago as it was unmaintained/dead.

Also, in your simple example, you are not using `pyglet.app.run()` which is required for the clock to schedule the samples to play. (And why your script stops immediately)

For Linux, Pyglet supports GStreamer and Ffmpeg, so you will have to install one of those libraries to continue to play media.

Comment: Sorry for not responding yet - inconveniently, my sound broke before I got a chance to test this